# PayPal - Disable Create Account option

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal Website Payments Standard.

Once payment has been completed using credit/debit, consumer then prompted to create paypal account which is misleading. If they don’t want to, they have to select ‘no thanks’ to exit.

Is there any way to stop PayPal from offering this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to disable this feature with the Website Payments Standard flow.